# How to solve error of number_to_currency convert decimal to comma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decimal

I have a column amount with type decimal.
If I save 6.00 and when I get number_to_currency it change this amount to 6,00.

Anyone know what this issue?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: You can change separator: `number_to_currency(6.00, separator: '.')`

Comment: You should submit an answer @inf. I suppose that the comma is included because it is the default for the current locale.

Answer (score 1):

number_to_currency formats a number into a currency based on your current locale. You can change default format by passing additional options, for example:

```
number_to_currency(6.00, separator: '.')
```